# Access a View within the UICollectionView cell that is positioned at the center of the device screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to change the background color of a View within a Collection View cell if the cell is located at the center of the device screen after scrolling has occurred.  I currently have a working method that can change the background color of the Views within all of the currently visible Cells after scrolling that looks like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{


    if(scrollView==_collectionViewFollwersFeed)
    {
        for (UICollectionViewCell *cell in [self.collectionViewFollwersFeed visibleCells]) {

            UIView *tsView;

            tsView=(UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:99];

            tsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        }
    }
}
```

When I tried to edit this method to only change the background color of the View within the Cell that is positioned at the middle, I am unable to get this functionality working.  Here is the adjusted that I believe should work:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{


    if(scrollView==_collectionViewFollwersFeed)
    {

        NSIndexPath *centerCellIndexPath =
        [self.collectionViewFollwersFeed indexPathForItemAtPoint:
         [self.view convertPoint:[self.view center] toView:self.collectionViewFollwersFeed]];

        UICollectionViewCell *cell;
        NSString *CellIdentifier;

        CellIdentifier = @"FollowersFeed";
        cell = [_collectionViewFollwersFeed dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:centerCellIndexPath];

        UIView *tsView = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:99];

        tsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea as to why this method does not change the View background color of the Cell at the center of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
cell = [_collectionViewFollwersFeed dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:centerCellIndexPath];
```

That is creating a new cell that isn't the one that your collection view is currently displaying.

To access the cell that is already in your collection view use:

```
cell = [_collectionViewFollwersFeed cellForItemAtIndexPath:centerCellIndexPath];
```